# Better questions should be featured in the tour

Tags: feature-request

If you hop over to the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour), you'll see that [Is it possible to Remove fields using Change Sets deployment?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41936/is-it-possible-to-remove-fields-using-change-sets-deployment) is the featured question.

Single sentence question, single sentence answer. Meeeeeeeeeeh.

I can think of plenty of [better options](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). Could it be changed? We wouldn't want to misguide new users here...

Comment: Could somebody create the [meta-tag:tour] tag?

Comment: [There's some strict criteria on which questions are available to choose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163948/237685). Here's [a list of the possible choices](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/92078/possible-about-questions#resultSets).

Comment: @hichris123 http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/10552/11524 looks slightly better.