# Which new tags should be added to this meta site?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Since I don't have the 2000 reputation needed for creating new tags here, I'll post tags that need to be created in the answer below. Feel free to add your own tags that need to be created (if they already have a question to add it to). Tags in answers, discussions of answers in comments.

So, which new tags should be added to this meta site?

Comment: I've got over 300 rep, but I can't edit any of the posts you reference.  Adding the tags on a question appears to be the only way to add them.

Comment: @Jagular Oh, that's right. To add them on to my questions you need 2k.

Answer (score 1):

- [flag](/questions/tagged/flag), synonym of [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging)
- [declined-flag](/questions/tagged/declined-flag), discussion about a declined flag (add [here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/775/11524))
- [tour](/questions/tagged/tour), https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour (add [here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/753/11524))
- [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center), https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help-center (add [here](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/778/11524))

Comment: I've created flag, tour and help-center. I don't think declined-flag is necessary. I don't have enough votes in flag or flagging to suggest a synonym.

Comment: @AlexTennant Thanks. With declined-flag I was hoping to recreate this [mso tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/declined-flags).