# Link to stackoverflow in help center

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

Under [the comment privilege](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), there is a link to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer ("pay it forward"). That should be https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Same on [meta](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this network-wide.